# Angular 6 - Portal

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-6

Preciso criar uma aplicação dos estilo portal em Angular 6. Esta aplicação deve ser capaz de incluir outras aplicações.

Explicando melhor:
Tenho 3 applicações:

- APP1
- APP2
- PORTAL

Dentro do Portal vao existir dois menus, um para a app1 e outro para a app2, quando o utilizador selecionar um destes menus a aplicação deverá ser exibida dentro do portal e deve correr de forma independente.

O utilizador a dada altura pode querer mudar da app1 para a app2 e o portal deve permitir faze-lo, ficando com as duas aplicações a correr lado a lado.

Eu já pesquisei e encontrei 3 soluções distintas, cada uma com os seus prós e contras:

1. Por módulos
2. Por aplicação
3. Por aplicação dentro de outra aplicação (Nova funcionalidade do Angular 6)

São estas as unicas soluções?

Qual será a melhor solução para resolver este problema? Tendo em conta o seguinte:

- Todas as aplicações vão precisar de ter componentes, serviços, directivas, etc partilhados
- O portal deve ser capaz de comunicar com as aplicações filho (incluidas dentro do portal)

Segue um link Adobe XD com um exemplo a ilustrar de forma simples o que pretendo

https://xd.adobe.com/view/13f6f93c-35d0-4d43-5154-47aeaa62c3ec-65c7/?fullscreen

Obrigado!

Comment: Acredito que o melhor é criar em módulos e separar as rotas por módulos dessa forma você consegue controlar as duas aplicações pelo portal.

Comment: Adicionando ao caso do @LucasBrogni, você vai ter de usar pelo menos dois `router-outlet`s para fazer algo similar ao exemplo mostrado. E quando alterar as "abas" do sistema, você vai precisar armazenar as variáveis em algo como o localStorage, para poder voltar ao estado da aplicação antiga ao voltar a nova (Indo da aplicação 1 para a 2, guardar os dados da 1 e re-atribuí-los às variáveis quando voltar a 1, guardando os da 2 para caso volte a ela)

Comment: Obrigado pelas vossas respostas, A solução por módulos era a que já tinha como a mais indicada, para guardar o estado de cada aplicação já dei uma vista de olhos no ngrx/store que permitir armazenar o estado de componentes. O único problema desta solução, para mim, é que quando um módulo/aplicação tiver de ser alterado é obrigatório publicar a aplicação completa.